# Why can't I use an if statement instead of using assert in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, exception, assert

Since `assert` simply checks if the statement in its parameter holds true or not, why don't we simply use an `if` condition to check that?

> Usage of assert

```
void print_number(int* somePtr) {
  assert (somePtr !=NULL);
  printf ("%d\n",*somePtr);
}
```

> Usage of if

```
void print_number(int* somePtr) {
  if (somePtr != NULL)
       printf ("%d\n",*somePtr); 
}
```

Can anybody point out the difference between the two and advantages of using one over the other?

Also, why do most people prefer `assert` over `if` here?

Comment: Here's a clue. Go look at your compiler's header files, and see how the `assert()` macro is defined. You'll be surprised.

Comment: `assert()` is for debugging purposes only, and it's effect will be usually taken out for production code. If you need to use `if()` to do some check that can be recovered and should be detected as an error condition by the caller, just use it.

Comment: The difference is that one of the functions returns and the other does not.

Comment: `Since assert simply checks if the statement in its parameter holds true or not` - this is not true. That's not what an `if` statement does either. They both take different actions if the parameter holds true (even ignoring the fact that assert only takes place when asserts are enabled).

Comment: Passing by reference would avoid this problem here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An assert should never fire in correct code. If it does, there is a bug in your code, and it needs to be fixed. So with a function like this:

```
void print_number(int* somePtr) {
  assert (somePtr!=NULL);
  printf ("%d\n",*somePtr);
}
```

You are saying that a null pointer should never be passed to this function, and if it is, then the code that passed it is incorrect.

However, with your function here:

```
void print_number(int* somePtr) {
  if (somePtr != NULL)
       printf ("%d\n",*somePtr); 
}
```

You are saying that it is okay to pass a null pointer to this function, it just doesn't do anything in that case.

A more appropriate function to compare your assert version with would be something like this:

```
void print_number(int* somePtr) {
  if (somePtr == NULL)
      std::abort();
  printf ("%d\n",*somePtr);
}
```

That does essentially the same thing as assert (though without the useful diagnostic message). The difference here is that asserts disappear if `NDEBUG` is defined. This function (with the if, then abort) would make the check under all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anybody point out the difference between the two

If you take a look at this [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert), you'll find that the condition of `assert` is not checked if `NDEBUG` macro is defined. Also, if the condition is not satisfied, then `std::abort` will be called.

The condition of `if` statement is always checked. If the condition is not satisfied, then `std::abort` is not called - unless that is what `else` statement does.

> and advantages of using one over the other?

The advantage of `assert` is that you can use `NDEBUG` macro to control whether the condition is checked. The advantage of enabling the check is to be able to catch bugs when developing. The advantage of disabling the check is to avoid the check in a release build where the check might not be afforded.

The advantage of using a plain `if` statement would be that the bug can be caught in a release build as well. The disadvantage is the runtime cost of the conditional check.

Answer (score 1):

The main point of `assert` is to provide tests for correctness during development when speed doesn't matter and have those checks removed when the application is released.

The `assert` checks disappear when the `NDEBUG` macro is defined and because of this the program runs faster without them. So during development `NDEBUG` is undefined but when the application is compiled for release, `NDEBUG` is defined.

In `GCC` you can turn `assert` checks on for *development* mode:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -U NDEBUG ...
```

And turn them off for *release* mode:

```
g++ -O3 -g0 -D NDEBUG ...
```

A normal `if` statement will always run whether developing or in release code. Therefore `if()` has an impact on final performance when `assert` does not. Also an `assert` will cause the application to *terminate* immediately if it fails so they should be turned off in the final release.

Answer (score 0):

Using asserts provide you an easy way to validate values at **developing** time and ignore those checks at **production** time.

Paraphrasing what the SO documentation used to say:

> If an assertion fails and assertions are active, then the program stops with an error message (and often a core dump).  If assertions are not active (the code is compiled with `-DNDEBUG` or equivalent), then the check is not made and therefore the error is not reported.  A common practice is to leave assertions enabled in development (internal, debug) builds, and to disable assertions in release builds.